# New Definition Of Limits

Tags: calculus

Prove that the limit $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)$$ exists if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x, y$ in the interval $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ the inequality $$|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$ is satisfied.
$$$$Suppose that $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$ then suppose we are given a $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-c|<\delta$ we have $$|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and whenever $|y-c|<\delta$ we have $$|f(y)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and hence we have $$|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y)-L+L-f(x)| \leq |f(y)-L|+|L-f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$.
$$$$Now suppose the converse holds true then we have for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $N$ such that for all $x, y$ in the interval $(c-\frac{1}{N}, c+\frac{1}{N})$ we have $$|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$. Now choose a sequence $x_n$ converging to $c$ such that $x_n$ always lies in the interval $(c-\frac{1}{n}, c+\frac{1}{n})$.Now define a sequence $$a_n=f(x_n)$$. Then we have for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $N$ such that for all $m, n >N$ we have $$|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|=|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$$ and hence $a_n$ is a Cauchy's Sequence. Let this sequence converges to $L$. Then for every $\epsilon$ we can find a $N'$ such that for all $n>N'$ we have $$|a_n-L|<\epsilon$$. So choose $N_0=\text{max}(N', N)$. Also we see that for a given $\epsilon>0$ for all $y$ in the interval $(c-\frac{1}{N}, c+\frac{1}{N})$ a and for all $m>N$ we have $$|a_m-f(y)|<\epsilon$$. So for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $N_0$ such that for all $m>N_0$ and for all $|y-c|<\frac{1}{N_0}$ we have the inequality $$|f(y)-L|=|f(y)-a_m+a_m-L| \leq |f(y)-a_m|+|a_m-L| <2\epsilon$$ and as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary so we have $$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$$.
Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: The first part looks correct. When reading the second part I stopped directly and wondered if it can't be done easier: just take $y=c$.

Comment: But what if we add the condition that $x, y \neq c$

Comment: Well, that is not the case here. But I made a mistake, thinking about continuity instead of just limit. So my idea doesn't apply.

Comment: Your second part looks correct. Perhaps it can be simplified somewhat, though.